# docker run fails with "docker: Error response from daemon: Address already in use."

Tags: docker, ipv6, docker-run, docker-daemon

When I try to execute:

**docker run --name openldap --detach osixia/openldap:1.3.0 --network=development**

it fails with "address already in use"

If I run dockerd with the -D flag i can see it requesting an ip6 address, **fe80::42:242:ac11:2**, before it tries to exit but I do not seem to be able to control which ip6 address it requests, with either --ip6 or --link-local-ip

Answer (score 0):

make sure you execute the command correctly... i noticed in the daemon debug output that it was choosing the wrong network and it's because i've put the image before the last parameter to the command

it should be:

**docker run --name openldap --detach --network=development osixia/openldap:1.3.0**

and then it runs fine